# Bash parameter expansion: get entire remainder of a string after an offset

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

How can I avoid `rest=${burger:1:99999999999999}`, is there something that can replace the 9999999999 while still getting the remainder of the string burger ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `substring=${var:offset:len}`, the `:len` can be elided completely.

So just make it:

```
rest=${burger:1}
```